# Compiling a libGDX project with FreeTypeFontGenerator for iOS fails

Tags: ios, compilation, libgdx, xamarin

I am using FreeTypeFontGenerator to generate fonts for my libGDX game.

Earlier versions of the game, before I started using the generator, compiled to all platforms without problems.

When I have added the generator, however, I get this when trying to compile for iOS (through Xamarin Studio):

```
    [javac] import com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.g2d.freetype.FreeTypeFontGenerator;
    [javac]                                              ^
    [javac] /Users/erlenddahl/Copy/UltralydDebugging/Libgdx/Ultralyd/Ultralyd/src/no/mycompany/mygame/GameClass.java:170: cannot find symbol
    [javac] symbol  : class FreeTypeFontGenerator
    [javac] location: class no.mycompany.mygame.GameClass
```

I have added the generator to my project by following the steps in [this guide](http://www.badlogicgames.com/wordpress/?p=2300), spesifically like this:

> To use gdx-freetype, grab the latest nightlies, link gdx-freetype.jar and gdx-freetype-natives.jar to your desktop
>   project, link gdx-freetype.jar to your Android project, and copy the
>   armeabi/libgdx-freetype.so and armeabi-v7a/libgdx-freetype.so files to
>   your Android project’s libs/ folder, just like with the libgdx.so
>   files.

However, I notice that this says nothing about copying the .so files into the iOS project. I assume this is where my error lies, but unfortunately, the iOS project has no "armeabi" folders to put the .so files in, and I'm stuck.

Any suggestions?

Comment: just follow the link the p.t. has referred , that will solve your problem. Secondly .so files are meant only for android project, they dont have anything to do with ios project. Thirdly i would suggest to use fnt files in place of ttf files for fonts. it has high rendering performance and fast loading time.

Comment: Thank you. Are you saying that fnt files are better for performance than generating them with FreeTypeFontGenerator? How come, aren't both used to load the font data to memory?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The blog entry on iOS support for gdx-freetype has some specifics for finding/copying the right binaries on iOS.  I don't think iOS was originally supported (at the time the guide you reference was written):

http://www.badlogicgames.com/wordpress/?p=2819